# Html/JavaScript characters with accent

Tags: javascript, html

So i have a html page with some javascript in it.
I want to use it to open a `.csv` file. But every time the file loads all characters with accents (like: `á, í, ç, ã, ê and º`) it appear like this � .
The code:

https://pastebin.com/bhjkwktT

There is anyway to make the characters appear or, at least change to normal one (a,e,i, etc.)?

This "programm" will be in my close network, and using in different computers by share folder.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [mcve] **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 4):

What's happening is that the web page is using a different character encoding than the character encoding of the .csv file. This causes the character that is read from the .csv file to be decoded using a different mechanism that was used to encode it, resulting in the wrong character being displayed.

Make sure both files are saved in the UTF-8 format, rather than ANSI format and then in your web page, make sure this line appears at the beginning of the `head` section.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

---

Now, looking at the code you linked to, **your HTML is not even valid** as you have several elements that are not inside of the `head` element as they should be.

You have this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<title>Lista</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/csvtable.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.csvToTable.js"></script>
<link href="Lista.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

<head>

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<meta charset="utf-8" />    
</head>
<body>
```

With the `title`, `link` and `script` elements not inside the `head` section.

Additionally, you are using the HTML5 `DOCTYPE`, but then you specify the XHTML 1.0 namespace. You then go on to specify the encoding twice, using each language's syntax. You most likely (unless you have some specific reason) want HTML5.

It should be this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">   
    <title>Lista</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/csvtable.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.csvToTable.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Lista.css">
</head>
<body>
```

You should also make sure that your additional external files (the .css and .js files) are saved with UTF-8 encoding as well (don't worry about 3rd party files as this will have been done already).

In CSS files, saving the file with the correct encoding is usually enough, but you can go a step further and formally **[declare the encoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@charset)** by placing this at the very beginning of the .css file: `@charset "UTF-8";`

Comment: ...or just generally, make sure they're all saved in and reporting the same encoding, regardless of what it is (but UTF-8 is normally a great choice for western scripts).

Comment: Still not working, can it be in `reader.readAsText($("#fileUpload")[0].files[0]);` ?

Comment: @Noscente Why are you using the `FileReader` in the first place? Why not just do an AJAX call for the `.csv`?